# Shannon capacity of Union

Tags: it.information-theory

Alon showed that a counter example to the Shannon conjecture on the Zero-error capacity of disjoint union of graphs.

The conjecture is that the sum of Zero-error capacities of the constituent graphs in the disjoint union is the Zero-error capacity of the disjoint union.

Refer: http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FPL00009824

For what pairs of graphs is the Shannon conjecture true?